# inputField required mark with custom error msgs

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, input-field

I'm using an inputField that is binded directly to a custom objects field in the controller.
The following will generate a dropdown list with a label.

```
 <apex:inputField value="{!Agency_Profile.Location_Principal_Activity__c}" />
```

My problem is that I need to add the required mark next to the inputField without losing the label or having default error msgs.

when I used

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Agency_Profile.Location_Principal_Activity__c}" required="true"/>
```

I got the required mark but I lost my custom error msgs for validation.

when I used

```
<apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
     <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/> 
     <apex:inputField value="{!Agency_Profile.Location_Principal_Activity__c}" />
  </apex:outputPanel>
```

the labels near the dropdown list didnt show anymore..

Is there a way I can accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this.

```
//this part to add the missing label.
<apex:outputLabel styleclass="labelCol" value="{!$ObjectType.Agency_Profile__c.fields.Location_Principal_Activity__c.Label}" />

<apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
     <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/> 
     <apex:inputField value="{!Agency_Profile.Location_Principal_Activity__c}" />
  </apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add [validation rule](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_validation_considerations.htm) for this field for this object.

Comment: Adding that won't show a red mark near the field in the visualforce page.

Comment: I will check. But there even should be a field for input an error message.

Answer (score 0):

using raym0nds approach, this is how it looks for a **custom controller variable**, in my case with the name from a custom field of an object.:

```
//this part to add the missing label.
<apex:outputLabel for="myId" styleclass="labelCol" value="{!$ObjectType.Agency_Profile__c.fields.Location_Principal_Activity__c.Label}" />

<apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
     <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/> 
     <apex:inputText id="myId" required="true" value="{!myCustomField}" label="{!$ObjectType.Agency_Profile__c.fields.Location_Principal_Activity__c.Label}"  />
</apex:outputPanel>
```

note the `apex:inputText` type which now has an `label`, `id` and `required` attribute. The `apex:outputLabel` now has a `for` attribute. The `for/id` is just so clicking on the label will put the cursor into the right field. The `required` enables form validation, because the rest is just make-up. The `label` adds a good field name to that validation error - otherwise it would show the internal field id there.

the whole approach is interesting if you have a mass edit table in which all records share certain values (e.g. add multiple leads for the same company)